# error de sintaxis bash

Tags: linux, bash, github

He cambiado el código, ahora no me ejecuta la instrucción `dd`

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
echo "Bienvenido al instalador de sistemas operativos en pendrive"
echo "Indica dónde está la iso a intalar"
echo "Si quires salir pulsa la tecla p "
read ruta
        if [ $ruta = "p"  ]
                then
                        exit
        elif [ -z "$ruta" ]
                then
                         echo "Oiga, introduzca la ruta"
                 elif [ -f $ruta]
                         #Aquí comprobamos que la variable ruta no esté vacía y sea la ruta exacta donde cargar la imagen del sistema operativo a instalar.
                         then
                                echo "Ahora introduce la ruta donde está el pendrive"
                                        read rutapen
                                                 if [[ ( -n "$rutapen" ) && ( -d "$rutapen" ) ]]
                                                        then
                                                                `dd if=$ruta of=$rutapen`
                                                                #Aquí ejecutamos la instrucción que permite grabar las isos booteables
                                                        else
                                                                echo "La ruta no es correcta"
                                                fi
        fi

done
```

Comment: y esto ~ ? es parte del codigo?

Comment: Engancha el código en http://www.shellcheck.net/ para ver fácilmente qué errores sintácticos tiene.

Comment: Ya he modificado el script

Comment: Por favor, tómate un rato de tiempo para editar la pregunta de manera que sea comprensible: indica qué falla, dónde y bajo qué circunstancias. De otra forma, te estamos haciendo nosotros el debugging :)

Comment: Cuando meto la ruta del p

Answer (score 1):

Cuando compares `strings` utiliza las comillas y pon la variable dentro "$ruta"

```
    if [ "$ruta" == "p"  ]
            then exit
    elif [ "$ruta" != "" ]
```

Si quieres saber si una cadena es de longitud cero utilizas:

```
if [ -z "$ruta" ]
```

### otro error

Esto:

```
elif [[ ( -n "$ruta" ) &&  ( -f "$ruta" ) ]]
```

Debería ser escrito así:

```
elif [ -n "$ruta" ] &&  [ -f "$ruta" ]
```

O de esta otra forma

```
elif [ -n "$ruta" -a -f "$ruta" ]
```

En esta línea tienes el mismo error que el que mencione arriba:

```
if [[ ( -n "$rutapen" ) && ( -d "$rutapen" ) ]]
```

---

[Referencia (en ingles)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Answer (score 0):

La línea 
`elif [ $ruta !="" ]`
Está mal, no se puede comparar los strings de esa forma.
En su lugar usa esta sintaxis:
`elif [ $ruta -eq "" ]`

-eq es NO IGUAL

Comment: -eq quiere decir justamente es IGUAL A y sirve para enteros.